# Searching a datatable versus searching through a List<>

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine, datastore

First, my game is being made in Unity3D, utilizing a sqlite database.

Second, my database is used to store thousands of random star systems and their accompanying data (planets, stars, location etc etc)

What I want players to be able to do is to type in a systems "address" (for instance if there are 5 star systems inthe DB;

```
Sys001
Sys0012
Sys0013
Sys004
Sys050
```

and the user searches for `001`, then the search results will return;

```
Sys001, Sys0012, Sys0013
```

ignoring Sys004 and Sys050.

This will happen instantly/near instantly (extremely quickly) so if the user then adds another character (IE searches for `0013`) then the results will update in real-time instantly.

My question is....to achieve this, which would be better to use? Should I stick to just using my Database (IE using SQL functions to get this data) or would it be faster/better/easier/more ideal to import all database data into Lists, and then search the list (ie List[i].nameVariable.Contains("001") etc)

Comment: No, let the database do the search. It is optimized for such tasks and has appropriate data structures. Of course, you should help the database and specify an index for the according field.

Comment: I thought as much. I'd imagine it is also more secure?

What do you mean an index? As in Primary Key?

Edit: Also, slightly off topic - is it better to close the DB connection as soon as I am done with it then reopen it when its needed again - or would it be an idea to keep the connection open if it will definitely be used again in the likely near-future?

Answer (score 1):

If it's being accessed a lot and is used often, then yes, you can load it into memory in a collection and use that. If not, create an index on the address and search on the column. Again, if the DB is accessed often then open a connection at game start, reuse that connection and close at the end. If not, open it and close after use in those rate instances you need to access it - this just helps free up resources a bit.

Comment: Ok thanks. Another question, is there a way to 'stammer' the results? If I load all lthe results simultaneously (IE though;

    while(_reader.Read()) { //Add results to list }

then there is a considerably noticable amount of lag (the game freezes for 2-3 seconds). My original solution was to use a coroutine - which does work. However when I'm trying to run the 'Select' function from another clalss (through a static reference to the behaviour/script) I keep getting a nullReferenceException on anything to do with coRoutines :(

Comment: Sorry, not sure of the SQLite implementation details, but can offer some thoughts to test: often the most expensive part of the process is opening the connection, so isolate what the bottleneck is. If is the query, then see if there is a better method to use so you not looping through a reader.read(). Also, create a list/array with larger capacity so: var list = new List<int>(100); so there is less resizing being done internally.

Comment: Hm thank you I'll give it a shot - I've never really paid much attention to code optimization, let alone database optimization, but I may as well start now haha. I did manage to solve my issue, I put the while(reader.Read()) into a coRoutine which pauses after every 10 entries that is added to the list or so. It works fine with ~100 entries, but when I come to the final product, there will be thousands, so we'll see then if it is fixed haha